# Solving system of equations involving ratios and exponents

Tags: nonlinear-system

I have two equations,

$$\frac{x}{1-x}=\exp(A_{x}+Bx+Cy)$$
$$\frac{y}{1-y}=\exp(A_{y}+Cx+Dy)$$

I am interested in the number of solutions $(x,y)$ to these two equations as the parameters $A_{x},A_{y},B,C,D$ vary. If any help, I know that $B,C,D>0,B+2C+D<1$.

I'd appreciate any and all lead on studying these equations and the number of its solution.

Thank you very much for your help.

Best,

John